# scraping different dates through loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a python code to scrape one page from soccer results and odds website

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import copy
import numpy as np

results = []

d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

u = 'https://1x2.lucksport.com/result_en.shtml?dt=' + '2019-05-02' + '&cid=156'

d.get(u)
WebDriverWait(d, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#odds_tb tr[class]")))
soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
rows = soup.select('#odds_tb tr[class]')

headers = ['Comp', 'Time', 'Match' ,'Odds', 'H', 'A', 'Res']
i = 1
for row in rows[1:]:    
    cols = [td.text for td in row.select('td')]

    if (i % 2 == 1):
        record = {'Comp' : cols[0],
                  'Time' : cols[1],
                  'Match' : ' v '.join([cols[2], cols[6]]),
                  'Odds' : 'op',
                  'H' : cols[3], 
                  'A' : cols[5],
                  'Res' : cols[7]}
    else:
        record['Odds'] = 'cl'
        record['H'] = cols[0] 
        record['A'] = cols[2]
    results.append(copy.deepcopy(record))
    i+=1

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = headers)
d.quit()
```

I want to create a loop and scrape all previous dates  (for specific dates range (last month for example)), so I created a list of dates to use it on the loop:

```
D =  datetime.datetime.now().date()
date_list = [D - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 30)]
dates = []
for i in date_list:
    date = str(i)
    dates.append(date)
```

Then I tries to create the loop which I expected it to return a dataframe for all previous dates data

```
results = []

for date in dates:
    d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

    u = 'https://1x2.lucksport.com/result_en.shtml?dt=' + date + '&cid=156'
    i = 1
    d.get(u)
    WebDriverWait(d, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#odds_tb tr[class]")))
    soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
    rows = soup.select('#odds_tb tr[class]')

    headers = ['Comp', 'Time', 'Match' ,'Odds', 'H', 'A', 'Res', 'Date']

    for row in rows[1:]:    
        cols = [td.text for td in row.select('td')]

        if (i % 2 == 1):
            record = {'Comp' : cols[0],
                      'Time' : cols[1],
                      'Match' : ' v '.join([cols[2], cols[6]]),
                      'Odds' : 'op',
                      'H' : cols[3], 
                      'A' : cols[5],
                      'Res' : cols[7],
                     'Date' : date}
        else:
            record['Odds'] = 'cl'
            record['H'] = cols[0] 
            record['A'] = cols[2]
        results.append(copy.deepcopy(record))
        i+=1
        d.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = headers)
```

but it return an error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0668d7389fc6> in <module>
     33         cols = [td.text for td in row.select('td')]
     34 
---> 35         if (i % 2 == 1):
     36             record = {'Comp' : cols[0],
     37                       'Time' : cols[1],

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is type `datetime.date` due to

```
D =  datetime.datetime.now().date()
date_list = [D - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 30)]
dates = []
for i in date_list:
```

`date_list` is a list of `datetime.date` , so `i` will be an element within this list and of that type.

You are trying to treat it as `int` later; hence your error.

```
if (i % 2 == 1):
```

Use another loop counter variable or change `i` for when iterating `date_list` e.g.

```
import datetime
D =  datetime.datetime.now().date()
date_list = [D - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 30)]
dates = []
i = 1
for iDate in date_list:
    if (i % 2 == 1):
        print(i)
    i+=1
```

---

Side note:

your `d.quit()` is inside the For Loop and could be after it, and  `d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')` could be before the loop. Then you work with only one instance from start to finish.

Comment: I changed the i, but didn't worked, the first link is ok (browser opened), but the second link didn't start and the program is running since 10 mn without any result and without showing any browser

Comment: can you first move your  d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe') to before the For Loop and have your d.quit() after the loop. You only need to create once and work with that instance.   And i = 1 should be before the loop as well and incremented in the loop; not reset to i each time inside the loop.